# Rails array to jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to add AJAX for delete action of my controller following [railscast 136 - jQuery AJAX revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)

It deletes element I choose but it doesn't disappear from the page.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to create propper jQuery selector.

I would be ok to use `$('#slide_<%= @destroyed_slide_id %>').remove();` for just one slide (no array) but my controller provides `@destroyed_slides_ids` **array**. How to create selector from it ?

Comment: Do not edit your question’s title with “solved”, instead accept an answer to mark it as so. You can accept your own answer to a question after 48 hours.

Comment: Those 48 hours are exactly the reason why I added (solved) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way. jQuery selector can be used to select multiple elements at once:

```
$('<%= @destroyed_slides_ids.map { |slide| "#slide_" + slide.to_s }.join(', ') %>').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over each id in the `@destroyed_slides_ids` array

```
<% @destroyed_slides_ids.each do |id| %>
    $('#slide_<%= id %>').remove();
<% end %>
```